# How to fix Azure-Powershell "hello world"-task that fails with error: Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: '6.2.3'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

I'm setting up an Azure devops pipeline in which I want to manipulate resources in my subscription. For this I try to use an AzurePowerShell task.

I trimmed down my attempts to a most basic hello world example that connects with my subscription:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019
trigger: none

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'hello world'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azure-connection-dev'
    azurePowerShellVersion: '6.2.3'
    inline: |
      Write-Output "Hello"
      Write-Output "world"
```

When I trigger this pipeline I expect the pipeline to print "Hello world" but instead it fails with

```
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 4.157.4
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613749)
==============================================================================
##[error]Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: '6.2.3'. If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure
```

What is wrong with the above hello world example?

Comment: where you got that version from? I see latest AZ module version is 2.7 and AZ.Accounts 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

The error message is unambiguously telling you the **exact** problem: The hosted agent doesn't have Az 6.2.3 on it. The available versions are [documented](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md). If you need a version that's not installed by default, you'll need to install it with `Install-Module` first.

The Azure Powershell task starts by logging in to your Azure subscription with the specified service connection. Since you're telling it to use an unavailable version, it's trying to load the module and immediately failing.